# How to redirect my action filter class to retrn a view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following class to implement a custom authorization system:-

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
    public class CheckUserPermissionsAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        Repository repository = new Repository();
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public string Action { get; set; }

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            string ADusername = filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name.Substring(filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name.IndexOf("\\") + 1);
            if (!repository.can(ADusername,Model,Action))            {
                filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult("You cannot access this page");


            }

            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
```

but currently when accessing my web application using Firefox,and if the  `filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult("You cannot access this page");` is return the user will keep getting a prompt windows to enter username and password forever. so is there a way to modify my action method so that instead of returning  `filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult("You cannot access this page");`, to return to a view that show a message such as "You are not authorized to do this action..".
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could return a [`ViewResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewresult%28v=vs.108%29.aspx):

```
var viewResult = new ViewResult();
viewResult.ViewName = "~/Views/Errors/Unauthorized.cshtml";
filterContext.Result = viewResult;
```

You could of course set other properties on this view result instance such as the layout and a possible view model if needed by the view.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but where exactly I should add this code; inside the If statement or after the              base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
 ?

Comment: Inside the `if` statement which is where you are currently returning an `HttpUnauthorizedResult`.